# Android Get Time Between onPause and onResume

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I want to be able to calculate the time between onPause and onResume for my app to know where an animation should be when the user comes back to the app. Here is what I am trying:

```
long onPauseTime;
long onResumeTime;

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    onPauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause: " + onPauseTime);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    onResumeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: " + onResumeTime);
    Log.d(TAG, "Time Gone: " + (onResumeTime-onPauseTime));
}
```

But onPauseTime is always 0 in the onResume method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: onPause is called when you leave tha Activity

Comment: Try saving the onPauseTime in a SharedPreferences

Comment: Right. If onPause is called when the user leaves the activitiy, and onResume is called when they come back, I want to the the difference of those two times.

Comment: Making them static worked

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, so that you can save the time and still know how long its been if your activity gets destroyed.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

            //Class used to store data
            private SharedPreferences preferences;

            public void onResume(){
                super.onResume();
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                long start = preferences.getLong("time",0);

                long elapsed = end - start;

            }

            public void onPause(){
                super.onPause();
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
                ed.putLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
                ed.commit();
            }
        }
```